# Need help blocking 3 digit prefixes

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^\+1242((35[79]|37[56]|46[^019]|44[^2]|4[^0169]\d|5[^0189]\d|6[34]\d|395|72\d))
```

I am stuck on the `"4[^0169]\d"` section.

Correctly, if you enter `+1242413` this does not match. Same goes for something like `+1242401`. It does correctly match on `+1242441` (i,e it is permitted).

I am stuck in that I also want to block `"442"` as in `+1242442`. This should not much (just like +1424401 in the above example). However, `441` or `443` or `444`, etc. should match. So `+1242441` should be a successful match on the regex.

How can I expand on `4[^0169]\d` to also not-match `442` along with the ones already blocked?

Comment: @anubhava: please solve it and save us!

Comment: what is goal in a more general way Mr flinchböt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is just to permit values you want to allow (like you've already done):

```
^\+1242((35[79]|37[56]|46[^019]|44[^2]|4[^01469]\d|5[^0189]\d|6[34]\d|395|72\d))
```

So I've disallowed `44*` (through `4[^01469]\d`) but allowed everything but `442` (through `44[^2]`) as an alternative.

Note, however, that under this pattern, `124244a` would also be allowed. To fix that you'd have to rethink how your pattern so that it would only contain positive character classes:

```
^\+1242((35[79]|37[56]|46[2-8]|44[013-9]|4[23578]\d|5[2-7]\d|6[34]\d|395|72\d))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can use option 1 as characters are already filtered out before it gets this far. However, there is no problem with option 2 and it may be the easier one to use for further edits. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the advice given in the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)'s tooltip, you have not provided the language/flavor that you are using. If it supports [zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), then the following should do the trick:

```
4[^0169]\d(?(?<=42)(?!))
```

I've appended a [conditional expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) which will check to see if the previous two characters were `42`. If they were, then `(?!)` will force the expression to fail.